# Oracle Job Scheduler(Creating a Local External Job That Runs a DOS Command) : couldn't execute Rscript.exe or javac.exe

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, dbms-scheduler

test.bat

```
mkdir C:\Users\user\aaTEST2
javac Test.java
Rscript C:\Users\user\a.R
```

above is the my bat file.
When i execute bat file with typing on window command, It goes well. but when i execute oracle job scheduler like:

```
BEGIN

DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
   job_name             => 'TEST_JOB2',
   job_type             => 'EXECUTABLE',
   number_of_arguments  => 3,
   job_action           => 'C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe',
   auto_drop            => FALSE);


DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE('TEST_JOB2',1,'/c');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE('TEST_JOB2',2,'C:\Users\user\test.bat');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('TEST_JOB2');

END;
```

it's executed without executing javac and Rscript. just only mkdir works out. why? what is the problem? my oracle version 12.1.0.1.0.

Comment: Well your personal command line environment and Oracle's scheduler-launched environment have different PATH settings. Can't you just set PATH, or provide the full path to the executables, in your `.bat` file?

Comment: should i write like this ?  -->                               C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac.exe                              but i got the message like not executable program...

Comment: Check that the corresponding Windows service is launched

Answer (score 0):

use below code create the credentials before create the job

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_CREDENTIAL.CREATE_CREDENTIAL(
      CREDENTIAL_NAME  =>  'credintial',   ----- credintial name give by u
     USERNAME         =>  'dons',           ----- os username
     PASSWORD         =>  'password');    ----- os password
END;
/


BEGIN
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB 
          (JOB_NAME=>'loader_file',       --- job name 
          JOB_ACTION=>'/home/oracle/loader.sh',    --- executable file with path 
          JOB_TYPE=>'executable',        -----   job type
          NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS=>7,  --  parameters in numbers 
          ENABLED=>false,                   
          AUTO_DROP =>true,
          CREDENTIAL_NAME=>'credintial',   -- give credentials name which you have created before "credintial"
          COMMENTS=> 'loader_file scheduler ');
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(JOB_NAME =>'loader_file', ARGUMENT_POSITION => 1, ARGUMENT_VALUE => 'para 1');
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(JOB_NAME =>'loader_file', ARGUMENT_POSITION => 2, ARGUMENT_VALUE => 'para 2');
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(JOB_NAME =>'loader_file', ARGUMENT_POSITION => 3, ARGUMENT_VALUE => 'para 3');
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(JOB_NAME =>'loader_file', ARGUMENT_POSITION => 4, ARGUMENT_VALUE => 'para 4');
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(JOB_NAME =>'loader_file', ARGUMENT_POSITION => 5, ARGUMENT_VALUE => 'para 5');
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(JOB_NAME =>'loader_file', ARGUMENT_POSITION => 6, ARGUMENT_VALUE => 'para 6');
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(JOB_NAME =>'loader_file', ARGUMENT_POSITION => 7, ARGUMENT_VALUE => 'para 7');
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('loader_file');
end;
/


begin 
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB('loader_file'); 
end;
/
```